# How to set colors for plot values in outside series ZingChart

Tags: json, zingchart

How to set different background colors for different value set outside the series array in zingchart ? Where should and how should i set my background-color-1 for value set1 and valu set2

```
var myConfig = {
    type: "mixed", 
    series : [
        {
          type : 'bar',
            values : [35,42,67,89,25,34,67,85],
            values : [30,40,60,80],
           // how to change background color without setting it here ?

        },
        {
          type : 'line',
            values : [35,42,67,89,25,34,67,85],
            lineWidth : "6px",
            topState : {
              lineWidth : "2px",
              lineColor : "pink"
            }
        }
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a working example of how to do it:
http://demos.zingchart.com/view/O79F20UY

The first array index in var palette represents the text color for the tooltips (on hover popup box) and the second array index in var palette represents the series color.

I came to an answer referencing some documentation on custom color palette's found here:
http://www.zingchart.com/docs/features/themes/

Feel free to reach out if you have any further questions - I am on the ZingChart team.